# problem with getting 2.1 speaker working under 12.04/unity/pulseaudio

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio

I have been using askubuntu extensively and now I am going to ask my first question here.

I am trying to get my 2.1 speaker working on my ThinkPad X60 and a 12.04LTS/unity/pulseaudio (00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)).

The front left/right is working fine, but I cannot get the lfe/subwoofer working.

Here is a subset of my pulseaudio conf:

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
...
default-sample-channels = 3
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe
```

I also notice the server sample tab in paman shows :

`Default Sample Type: s16le 3ch 44100Hz`

However in the device tab, the property of the sink is always s16le 2ch 44100Hz.

I also tried modify default.pa (`load-module module-remap-sink` OR `module-alsa-sink`) but it either doesn't work or switch to digital output which have no output at all.

Any idea will be very appreciated as this is something I have spent a whole morning to try to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwing steps:

1.

```
echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

2.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf
```

and add following lines to extra-hdmi.conf

```
[Mapping analog-surround-21]
device-strings = surround40:%f
channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe 
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker 
priority = 7 
direction = out
```

3.

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

and add following line to daemon.conf

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```